# Arranging divs and controlling resize behavior

Tags: html, css

(Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48phrdrn/))

I have a container split into three parts like this:

[image]

- **Container:** 100% width
- **A:** Will have 0 or 1 buttons inside
- **B:** Must take up the rest of the horizontal width until all children are shown, no wrapping, overflow is hidden (contents flow "off the screen")
- **C:** No line wrapping, will have 0 to 3 buttons inside

When it resizes smaller, **B** should get smaller and hide anything that doesn't fit:

[image]

When it resizes larger, it should resize until everything in **B** is visible, then **C** takes up the remaining space:

[image]

When I resize it, I can't get **C** to stay on the screen and just **B** get smaller.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <button>Button0</button>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-container">
        <ul class="middle">
            <li>Tab 1</li>
            <li>Tab 2</li>
            ..
            <li>Tab n</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <button>Button1</button>
        <button>Button2</button>
        <button>Button3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.left {
    float:left;
}

.middle {
    float:left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
    width:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-container ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

(Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48phrdrn/))

Comment: Are A and C have fixed width? Wich are?

Comment: Have you tried with media queries?

Comment: @giordanolima A and C will be fixed, but won't know until after the page has added in the buttons, which can vary in quantity

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 'middle' class from the ul tag and add that class to the 'nav-container' div, so it has both classes.

```
<div class="nav-container middle">
    <ul>
        <li>Tab 1</li>
        <li>Tab 2</li>
        ..
        <li>Tab n</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```